# es correcta esta validacion de tipo boolean en java?

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente validacion:

-La fecha de Inicio debe ser menor o igual a la fecha actual del sistema

-La fecha de Inicio debe ser igual o mayor a la fecha de Solicitud

En caso de que una validacion o ambas no se cumplan lanzan mensaje, y si las dos se cumplen, pues no pasa nada.
es correcto la forma en que esta planteada? 
en mi return manda un Output, esa es una clase interna que uso en este mismo codigo, la cual contiene los atributos de mensajes y respuesta con sus get and set y su constructor.

Hay alguna otra forma de hacer en una sola validacion y que me lanze los diferentes mensajes dependiendo en donde falla??

```
public Output apply(Input input){

    Date dateToday = new Date();
    boolean respuesta = false;

    String mensaje29 = "";
    String mensaje94 = "";

     if (input.getSolicitudP().getCertifi().getFechaInicio().before(dateToday)
                || input.getSolicitudP).getCertifi().getFechaInicio().equals(dateToday)) {
            respuesta = true;
        } else {
            respuesta = false;
            mensaje29 = "Verifica fecha";
        }

     if (input.getSolicitudP().getCertifi().getFechaInicio().equals(input.getSolicitudP().getPen().getFechaSoli())
                || input.getSolicitudP().getCertifi().getFechaInicio().after(input.getSolicitudP().getPen().getFechaSoli()))
        {

            respuesta = true;

        } else {
            mensaje94 = "ALGO";
        }

        return new Output(respuesta, mensaje29, mensaje94);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que describes es correcto lo que haces.

Para hacer tu código un poco más claro y liviano te sugiero los siguientes refacturaciones:

```
public Output apply(Input input){

    Output out = new Output();
    Date dateToday = new Date();

    // usa "despues" y procesa solamente el caso de falla
    if (input.getSolicitudP().getCertifi().getFechaInicio().after(dateToday){
        // se agrega un error, la validación se deja al Output.
            out.error(Output.FECHA);
        }

    // usa "antes" y procesa solamente el caso de falla
    if (input.getSolicitudP().getCertifi().getFechaInicio()
            .before(input.getSolicitudP().getPen().getFechaSoli())){
        // se agrega un error, la validación se deja al Output.
            out.error(Output.ALGO);
        }

     return out;
}

public class Output(){

    public static final String FECHA = "Verifica fecha!";
    public static final String ALGO = "algo...";
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public boolean valido(){
        // si no hay errores agregados, el resultado es valido
        return (sb.toString().length()==0);
    }

    public void error(String error){
        // agregar errores
        sb.append(error + "\n");
    }
}
```

La refacturación se basa en los siguientes recomendaciones para código más simple:

- Si puedes evitar un `else`, hazlo.
- DRY (don`t repeat yourself - no te repites)
- Si tienes varios condiciones de éxito y solo una de falla, comprueba la falla y invierte el resultado
- calcula las informaciones donde los necesitas

Answer (score 1):

No está mal, pero si tu validación todo lo que tiene que hacer es tirar un mensaje, pues entonces no veo necesidad de crear una clase para eso.

Yo, en bien de la legibilidad, lo haría así:

```
/* devuelve String vacio si ok, de lo contrario mensaje de error */
public String validar(Solicitud solic){
    Date fechaHoy= new Date();
    Date fechaInicio = solic.getCertifi().getFechaInicio();
    Date fechaSolicitud = solic.getPen().getFechaSoli();
    if ( ! comparaFecha(fechaInicio,fechaHoy) <= 0) 
        return "Fecha inicio debe ser menor o igual a fecha actual";
    else if ( ! comparaFecha(fechaInicio,fechaSolicitud ) >=0) 
        return "La fecha de Inicio debe ser igual o mayor a la fecha de Solicitud";
    else 
        return "";
    }

   /* devuelve 0 si son iguales, negativo si d1 es menor, positivo si d1 es mayor */
    public static comparaFecha(Date d1,Date d2) {
       return d1.compareTo(d2); // OJO: esto probablmente esta mal
    }
```

Pero hay un pequeño problema aquí (y en tu código) : estamos usando la clase `Date` de Java, que tiene millones de problemas. Para empezar, no representa una fecha sino un instance de tiempo (con horas y minutos...), así que (al parecer) no corresponde a lo pedido. Habría que utilizar un `Calendar` ,  o mejor todavía, las [nueva API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) de Java 8 - en particular [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)